# ActionBarSherlock in > Honeycomb application

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Is there any benefit of using ActionBarSherlock instead of native android api, if the application is only targeting  HoneyComb and above?

Answer (score 1):

`ActionBarSherlock` uses native ActionBar on API 14+ (Ice Cream Sandwich) as @CommonsWare said. This library is

> designed to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across
>   all versions of Android with a single API
>   ([actionbarsherlock.com](http://actionbarsherlock.com/))

The library will automatically use the native action bar when appropriate.

So there aren't  many Honeycomb devices (most are getting upgraded), and if the differences between Honeycomb and ICS aren't an issue for your app you don't need to use ABS.

Comment: Actually, it only uses the native action bar on API 14+ (Ice Cream Sandwich). Google made some changes to the `ActionBar` API and such between Honeycomb and ICS, such that ActionBarSherlock still uses its own for Honeycomb. That being said, there are not that many Honeycomb devices (most are getting upgraded), and if the differences between Honeycomb and ICS are not an issue for your app, skipping ActionBarSherlock is a fine plan.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the info, I didn't know it, because the documentation still says that native is used on 11+.

Comment: Check out the FAQ: http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html *"Why isn't the native action bar used on Android 3.x?"* "The action bar on Android 3.x (also known as Honeycomb) does not implement all of the features of the one in Android 4.x (Ice Cream Sandwich). In order to provide a full action bar API on all platforms as well as unify the styling across all versions of Android the custom implementation is used."

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now everything is clear. If I may, I will supplement my answer using your comments.

Comment: You are welcome to do whatever you want with your answer. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. I was in fact planning to get a subscription to your service and catch you tomorrow during the chat :-)